# Polynomial factorization with three variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need for factor the following polynomial. I have been looking for ways of doing it, but most of the resources show the simple example where everything beautifully factors. The problem is motivated by the need to prove that the geometric mean is less than or equal to the arithmetic mean, namely,

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[3]{abc} \leq (a + b + c)/3
\end{equation}

The textbook suggests to write $a$, $b$, and $c$ as $r^3$, $s^3$, and $t^3$ where $r, s, t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Rewriting the expression I have reached this expression, but do not know how to proceed from here.

\begin{equation}
r(r^2 - st) + s(s^2 - rt) + t(t^2 - rs) \geq 0 
\end{equation}

Comment: Worth memorizing this one, $r^3 + s^3 + t^3 -3rst$  is divisible by $(r+s+t)$    Or $$  (r+s+t)(r^2 + s^2 + t^2 -st-tr-rs)  = r^3 + s^3 + t^3 - 3rst$$

Comment: @WillJagy I checked that on Wolfram, but what procedure did you follow? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I have that one memorized, also   the one of degree four that goes   with Heron's formula for the area of a triangle.

Comment: @WillJagy Okay. I guess I'll do the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @paul $\;r,s,t\,$ are the roots of $\,z^3 - (r+s+t) z^2 + (rs+st+tr) z - rst = 0$ $\iff z^3 - rst = (r+s+t) z^2 - (rs+st+tr) z\,$. Write it for each of $\,r,s,t\,$ and add them up.